# How do I backup Wpa.dbl from recovery console?

Tags: windows-xp, backup, windows-activation

I know that a system repair will wipe out my Activation files so I need to backup the Wpa.dbl and another file int he System32 root.  I unfortunately can't boot into windows right now due to BSOD half way through booting.  I've decided to run a windows repair but I want to backup all things activation related first.  Can anyone shed some light on how to do this, I've not really worked with the recovery console much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need these 2 files:

**WPA.DBL** and **WPA.BAK**

location: %SystemRoot%\System32 (normally C:\Windows\System32)

copy them to floppy or USB stick.

once you have your systen restored, restart the computer and press F8 on boot up and then select to start in Minimal Safe Mode in “Advanced Boot Options” menu.

Open My Computer or Windows Explorer.

Navigate to the %SystemRoot%\System32 folder (normally C:\Windows\System32). You may have to click on the Show the contents of this folder link to display the files.

Rename the WPA.DBL and WPA.BAK (if exists) that currently reside in the directory.

Copy the original WPA.DBL and WPA.BAK previously backed up to the %SystemRoot%\System32 folder.

Restart the computer. Windows XP should be activated instantly and automatically.

*[Source](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/12/14/backup-and-save-the-windows-xp-activation-status-wpadbl-to-reinstall-without-activate-again/)*

p.s.: of course you can also use a **[BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/)** Live CD (supports USB) to recover any files you may need from the system if you're not comfy with the console.

Comment: will a recovery delete them if I simply back them up under a different name in the same directory?

Comment: the Bart PE stuff looks very cool, I've never heard of it before.  From reading it sounds like a custom safe mode

Comment: i don't really know your system and the recovery method used. rule of thumb: better safe than sorry. and BartPE is Live Windows environment booting from CD or USB (check WinToFlash) allowing you to access and/or backup files from a 'broken' system.

Comment: you're more than welcome.